# ActionBar is missing after switching to API21 AppCompat

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-appcompat

While working on the Big Nerd Ranch's Criminal Intent project when I updated my AppCompat library from API 19 to API 21 I lost ActionBar. I have tried changing themes around but I can't find a way to get ActionBar.

The full source code is available [here](https://github.com/donniezazen/The-Big-Nerd-Ranch-Guide/tree/master/CriminalIntent2).

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.sudhirkhanger.app.criminalintent" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity android:name=".CrimeListActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".CrimePagerActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**style.xml**

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To use `appcompat-v7`, you *must* inherit from `ActionBarActivity`. `CrimeListActivity` inherits from `SingleFragmentActivity`, which in turn inherits from `FragmentActivity`, not `ActionBarActivity`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I am kinda a lost here. If I change `FragmentActivity` to `ActionBarActivity` in both `SingleFragmentActivity` and `CrimePagerActivity` I get the `ActionBar`. I am not sure how that might break the app.

Comment: @donniezazen: I doubt that it will break anything, as `ActionBarActivity` itself inherits from `FragmentActivity`. Make sure that if you try to use the action bar from Java that you call `getSupportActionBar()`, not `getActionBar()`. Also, please bear in mind that using books that are 20-plus months old is going to be a problem, as Android is a swiftly changing platform. That book predates `appcompat-v7`, Android Studio, etc.

Comment: Thanks. I do am facing the problem for using an old book. I am half way done. I might as well go through it. I plan to read your highly recommended book next.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this issue as well.

The solution is remove the style tag from the `manifest.xml` (`android:theme="@style/AppTheme"`).

It will use the holo theme, but with the Action Bar.

Comment: This thing of theme is a P.I.A.

Answer (score 0):

I also had that problem I moved the whole line (`android:theme="@style/AppTheme`) and its works! The theme is a dark theme which looks better.