# Not seeing action bar for every activity that isn't MainActivity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar

I am building an app that starts activities through intents. The design of my activities in `XML` shows an action bar but whenever I am debugging on a physical android device, every activity besides `MainActivity` loses the action bar.

The entire app bar disappears and the layout continues as if there isn't supposed to be one. What are some of the first places to look to fix this?

How it looks in Android Studio preview

[image]

How it looks on a physical device

[image: image2]

Comment: share your code and style.xml

Comment: Kindly share your code, so that people can look what's missing in it.

Comment: share your Manifest.xml too

Comment: please Add your manifest.xml file.

Comment: Most likely, your activity does not inheret from `AppCompatActivity` but you are using an appcompat style in the `AndroidManifest`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27732341/actionbar-is-missing-after-switching-to-api21-appcompat

Comment: Thanks guys, sorry for not including code originally..was not sure entirely what to share. It was a combination of using NoActionBar themes and not using AppCompatActivity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check your theme you apply on activity or application.
if it has below code then it will not show you default action bar.

```
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
```

try to remove this line to get default action bar or add action bar using `<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar`

Answer (score 0):

I might recommend using the `Toolbar` instead of `ActionBar` to ensure you are always getting a `Toolbar` on the desired activity. The Android Developer Docs do a great job at explaining how to add the `Toolbar` to any activity.

https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/index.html